# Attributes of abstract class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have been learning OOPS in python and finding it a bit different from that of Java. In the below code I have written an abstract class and implemented it. Is it the right way to define the attributes of an abstract class?

```
class Vehicle(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def color(self):
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def regNum(self):
        pass

class Car(Vehicle):

    def __init__(self,color,regNum):
        self.color = color
        self.regNum = regNum
```

Is this a better way to do this?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class Vehicle(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self,color,regNum):
        self.color = color
        self.regNum = regNum

class Car(Vehicle):


    def __init__(self,color,regNum):
        self.color = color
        self.regNum = regNum


car = Car("red","EX9890")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to define abstract properties in an abstract base class, you can't have attributes with the same names as those properties, and you need to define concrete implementations of the properties in the concrete child class:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Vehicle(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def color(self):
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def regNum(self):
        pass

class Car(Vehicle):

    def __init__(self, color, regNum):
        self._color = color
        self._regNum = regNum

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @property
    def regNum(self):
        return self._regNum


c = Car("foo", "bar")  # works fine; would not work if abstract methods weren't implemented
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your code. i added some more code, can you please review it? :)

Comment: The "better way" here is not to define the `Vehicle` class, or to make `Vehicle` non-abstract and remove `Car`.  You're not doing anything that benefits from inheritance, much less abstract inheritance.